How to auto-create the database with Spring Boot in production mode
I'm trying to automatically create my production database on application startup since I'm using the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate application.properties property in production. I tried a lot of ways and nothing worked satisfactorily and apparently most things don't execute before the dataSource is auto-configured. The closest solution I found was the following:
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource(); // I don't want to override the default data source from the Spring Boot auto-configuration, can we fetch the data source that Spring Boot would normally return?
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Custom logic executed before DataSource is fully used.");
    }
}

My init() method is executed which I can use to create the production database before the database is accessed. Because afterwards, there would be an exception due to the database not existing and Spring Boot terminates the application.
I don't want to override or mess with the dataSource which Spring Boot already nicely auto-configures with Hikari, neither do I want to hardcode using Hikari. If I run the configuration class above in my Spring Boot application, the properties from my application.properties file are not auto-configured since my database connection properties end up missing (Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.).
How can I just inject a method before the dataSource bean is used or maybe there's another straight-forward way to create a database before Spring Boot tries to access it?

What do you mean by creating the database? Literally create the database or just initialize the schema? Take a look at things like Flyway and Liquibase for this don't try to re-invent the wheel.

@M.Deinum: I already use Liquibase but my schema migrations do not cover literally creating the database (not the schema). Also, you may not modify or insert any migrations into the chain at the start, only at the end as far as Liquibase is concerned

Hence my question what do you mean by creating the database. I would say letting your application creating the physical database is a bad idea, not to mention that different databases handle this differently (Oracle it is a user, MySQL has schema's etc.).

Doesn't look like a good idea for production, but there is a way how you can do that.
At first, you can't do that in your configuration class as this code should be executed before spring creates context, but you can use ApplicationContextInitializer for that:
public class DatabaseInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        createDatabase();// DB creation logic
        setSystemProperties(applicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }

    private void setSystemProperties(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
        //Credentials for newly created DB should be specified here
        environment.getSystemProperties().put("spring.datasource.url", [DB_URL]));
        environment.getSystemProperties().put("spring.datasource.username", [DB_USERNAME]));
        environment.getSystemProperties().put("spring.datasource.password", [DB_PASSWORD]));
    }

As you understand you will need to use a simple JDBC Connection for that.
After that, you will need to register this initializer:
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.addInitializers(new DatabaseInitializer());
        application.run(args);
    }
}

Hope it will help.
